# compiling c++ program, and linking against libraries compiled with another compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, linker

Suppose I have a c/c++ program that depends on dynamic libraries,
and suppose that the libraries where compiled using a new compiler (example: gcc-5.4), and then I've switched gcc to 4.8, then tried to compile/link my c++ program against these libraries..
Should the program be linked with no problems? And if the answer is no, then, why?

In fact, I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04, and I've build boost_1_63 using
gcc-5.4,
Then I switched to gcc-4.8 and tried to build a program against these libraries. How ever, the process failed..

When I rebuilt boost using the same version, everything was okay!

Can anybody tell me what is going behind the scene, please?

Thanks

Comment: g++ and its libraries changed a lot between those versions, because of the mad dash to implement C++11 and C++14.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  C++ supports function overloading and some compilers and linkers use *name mangling* to get around it.  There is no name mangling in C.

Comment: Is your C/C++ program a combination of C modules and C++ modules?

Comment: There is no standard C++ ABI, so you can't generally do this. There is also no standard C ABI, but you are more likely to be able to link C functions..

Comment: ABI notwithstanding, binaries compiled from C++ code are dependent on the *implementations* of all classes they use, including private members.  Inasmuch as class library implementations -- such as the STL's, for instance -- cannot be relied upon to be static, binaries built against one C++ implementation cannot be assumed to be binary compatible with binaries built against a different one.  Not even for two different versions of the same implementation.